# How to send an admin specific password reset email to admins using Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using Devise for normal users and admin users. They each have separate login pages, controllers, and model classes. However, when I trigger a password reset as an admin, the email that I receive is the same as the normal users (which includes the incorrect URL). It should be sending an email that has the correct URL for admin users. How can I configure/customize Devise so that I can achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is look for the email template Devise is using to send the reset email, it's usually located here: `/app/views/devise/mailer/reset_password_instructions.html.erb` in there  you have this line `<p><%= link_to 'Change my password', edit_password_url(@resource, reset_password_token: @token) %></p>` Which you'll need to modify to conditionally send a different address for password resets if the user is an admin.

You could do a `rake routes` in your terminal window to see what routes you have available and use the one for administrators in the administrators condition... or you could hard code it, but usually one would use a route helper whenever possible.

Hope that helps.